# Anylogic - Error while drawing animation frame

Tags: runtime-error

I have a model and everything was working fine. i was just changing some values to try different scenarios and adding some graphs when I got the error msg:

> Error while  drawing animation frame. possibly created by dynamic properties of animation shapes

The only message I could get from the console window is:

> Error during model creation:
>   java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Double

what could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you might have attempted to convert a string into a double.

```
String Message = "1.20";
double res = (double)Message;
```

The above code is not allowed in Java

A condition like this might have occurred.
You are not allowed to put a string into a double variable:

```
double res = "1.2";
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I don't think that could be the problem. If that was the case, I would get an error during model build up, which wasn't the case.